How to ventilate roof with beam in the way?
I'm wondering what the best way to ventilate the roof is with this beam in the way. I'm in the process of renovating a house built in 1900. I'm going to be having a new standing seam metal roof put on soon. I'm trying to figure out the best way to insulate and vent the roof. The home is a cape cod style house with knee walls upstairs. I'd like to move the insulation to the roof so that I can use the attic space behind the walls.


Without seeing the overall structure of the place it's hard to say. Show some context, please.

I'll have to take some pictures next time I'm there. With the beam in the picture being there though there's no way to vent from the bottom to the top.

I'm a bit concerned about the apparrent rafter shrinkage

@jasen the rafter looks massive 4x8? and appears to be resting on a slot in the ridge beam.  it only has to support the roof load.  new code trusses are made of new growth 2x4 if that.  crappy cutting job on what could have been beefy enough to hold up a car in the event a hurricane left one up there.

What's your ground snow load? The best move for you might just be to not vent your roof/attic...

@FreshCodemonger, I'm not sure where you get your size perspective. Looks like 2x6 rafter and 2x8 ridge board to me.

@user279198, ridges all over the U.S. have common ridge venting around a single ridge board like that. It's not really an issue. You state that "there's no way", but I tentatively disagree. Mostly, I want to know whether that wall continues past the roof or what.

@isherwood, the ridge vents I've seen installed require the sheathing not meet at the very top but it makes sense they would make another kind that would work with a ridge beam.  My roofer did tell me something similar though and I was only able to ridge vent from the truss portion of my roof.  They were probably just too lazy to source something that would work.  Be interested to know the product name if you've used one that works.

There's no specific type of ridge vent. You simply cut a channel as per normal. The ridge board is irrelevant. This whole question is moot.

@isherwood, looking at the ridge vent pictures the ridge vent is at the top and the ridge beam would be blocking 50% of it.  https://images.homedepot.ca/productimages/p_1000731232.jpg?product-images=l

I'm not sure how you come to that assessment considering we have no idea how big the beam is. Also, the sheathing and the void under the vent itself both allow airflow over the beam. I'm out until we get some details.

If you are redoing the roof then you can frame a false peak to the roof on the exterior and use a ridge vent on it.  You'd then just remove the sheathing between your actual peak and the false peak so it is open to air flow.

That's a fairly extensive modification. It's almost certainly not necessary.

yeah it might be a day of work depends on size of roof.  make the small fake trusses and sheet.

Why not just cut back the sheathing on either side of the ridge board?
